# Terracotta 3.7 DSO Clustered Quartz 2.1 ClassNotFoundException: com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl

Tags: java, exception, quartz-scheduler, terracotta

I am trying to upgrade quartz from 1.7 to 2.1 and Terracotta from 3.3 to 3.7.  I cannot get quartz to cluster properly with Terracotta 3.7 DSO (TerracottaJobStore).  My application runs just fine (with RAMJobStore) using Terracotta DSO.  I am able to get a simple standalone quartz example clustered with Terracotta 3.7 Express but of course our application will not run without DSO.

I am not quite sure why I am getting the following error, any help would be greatly appreciated, my only guess is quartz thinks I am running under Terracotta Express when I am in fact running Terracotta DSO, not sure why this would be though.  (We need DSO btw!)

---

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problem obtaining node id from TerracottaJobStore.
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1204)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.getScheduler(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1484)
    at controller.job.SimpleExample.run(SimpleExample.java:38)
    at controller.SController.<clinit>(SController.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:76)
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:943)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at 

org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:286)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandlers(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(SimpleUrlHandlerMapping.java:104)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:72)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:117)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1448)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at 

org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory.instantiate(StdSchedulerFactory.java:1194)
    ... 61 more

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.terracotta.quartz.AbstractTerracottaJobStore.init(AbstractTerracottaJobStore.java:62)
    at org.terracotta.quartz.AbstractTerracottaJobStore.getUUID(AbstractTerracottaJobStore.java:77)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl
    at org.terracotta.express.Util.getImplInstance(Util.java:14)
    at org.terracotta.express.ClientFactory.<clinit>(ClientFactory.java:14)
    ... 68 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.__tc_loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.terracotta.express.Util.getImplInstance(Util.java:11)
    ... 69 more


It gets this exception, Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.terracotta.express.ClientFactoryImpl, because terracotta toolkit runtime isn't included, which has this class, this is because we are using DSO and not express.  If I were to include that jar it would complain that I am using a terracotta bootjar. I am not sure how to get it to load up the correct DSO replacement to ClientFactoryImpl
```

---

```
    VM arguments: 
-Xbootclasspath/p:C:\Users\j\branch\Agg\dso-boot-hotspot_win32_160_30.jar -Xms80m -Xmx1500m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dtc.install-root=C:\Program Files (x86)\Terracotta\terracotta-3.7.0 -Dtc.config=C:\Users\j\branch\Agg\tc-config.xml -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\j\branch\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 -Dcatalina.home=C:\tomcat -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\j\branch\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\tomcat\endorsed -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 

Class path: 
C:\tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\spring-framework\2.5.6\jakarta-commons\commons-logging.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\spring-framework\2.5.6\log4j\log4j-1.2.15.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\spring-framework\2.5.6\slf4j\slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\spring-framework\2.5.6\slf4j\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\CoreTC\build\classes;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\zmq\2.1.10\zmq.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\apache-commons\lang\2.6\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-quartz-1.7\2.3.0\quartz-terracotta-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\quartz\2.1.5\quartz-all-2.1.5.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\lib\tools.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\spring-framework\2.5.6\cglib\cglib-nodep-2.2.3.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-quartz-1.7\2.3.0\tim-quartz-2.0-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-quartz-1.7\2.3.0\tim-quartz-2.x-ui-2.3.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-tomcat\tim-session-common-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-tomcat\tim-session-ui-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-tomcat\tim-tomcat-6.0-2.4.0.jar;C:\Users\j\branch\third-libs\lib\terracotta\tim-tomcat\tim-tomcat-common-2.4.0.jar

Library path: 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Imaging\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Users\j\workspace\third-libs\lib\zmq\2.1.7\win\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Shoreline Communications\ShoreWare Client\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenSSH\bin;.
Boot class path: 
C:\Users\j\branch\Agg\dso-boot-hotspot_win32_160_30.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\lib\modules\jdk.boot.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6_30\classes
```

---

```
quartz.properties

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true


org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.spi.InstanceIdGenerator = org.quartz.simpl.HostnameInstanceIdGenerator
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.terracotta.quartz.TerracottaJobStore
org.quartz.jobStore.tcConfigUrl = C:/Users/j/branch/Agg/tc-config.xml
```

---

Relevant Section of tc-config

```
<clients>
    <logs>terracotta/client-logs</logs>
    <modules>
        <module group-id="org.terracotta.toolkit" name="terracotta-toolkit-1.6" version="5.0.0" />
        <module name="tim-quartz-2.0" version="2.3.0" />
        <module name="tim-tomcat-6.0"/>
    </modules>
</clients>
```

I should note that we are using Spring 3.1.0, the reference to 2.5.6 are version independent files.

Comment: haha, just an update, my problem was that I accidentally included quartz-terracotta-2.3.0.jar.... I didn't know that was for Express, I knew tim-quartz-2.0-2.3.0.jar was for DSO but I thought I needed both, removing quartz-terracotta-2.3.0.jar fixed everything!